# How to convert an array of elements to an object in a MongoDB projection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I tried to use `$project` and `$arrayToObject` but I can't figure how it works. My MongoDB query returns an array of objects:

```
[{ amounts: [ 10, 20, 30 ], id: "0x3c93" }, { amounts: [ 0, 0, 100 ], id: "0xee10" }]
```

And I want to group the results by "id" as key and "amounts" as value:

```
{"0x3c93": [ 10, 20, 30 ], "0xee10": [ 0, 0, 100 ]}
```

What is the correct expression to achieve this projection? I am using the node.js driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `$group` them to an array and format them to `k`, `v` before using `$arrayToObject`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: 0, data: {$push: {k: "$id", v: "$amounts"}}}},
  {$project: {_id: 0, data: {$arrayToObject: "$data"}}},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$data"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Wn884bHic5s)

Comment: Thanks! Would you have a node.js example to use the cursor? I am getting this error: `MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $arrayToObject requires an object keys of 'k' and 'v'. Found incorrect number of keys:1`

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a node.js example